# Understanding Contraction Hierarchies

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding

I'm very interested by understanding how Contraction Hierarchies algorithm works. I have found this page : https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/contraction-hierarchies/ and read a lot of stuff. I understood how the algorithm goes and work except for one part. I didn't grasp how the contraction strategy really work. (Important: I'm not fluent in Maths).

In the first example on the page given above, the contraction order is 6→8→3→0→5→7→4→1→2→9 and I can't understand why. The explanations are not clear to me and [the original article](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/schultes/hwy/contract.pdf) contains too much maths in it.

Can someone, please, explain the strategy used to define the contraction order?
 Thanks.

Comment: Double post with better answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206495/understanding-contraction-hierarchies

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how they chose the order for their example. Every order results in a correct algorithm, so it doesn't matter much. Orders that avoid deep nesting and orders that avoid adding lots of shortcut edges improve efficiency, as observed in both the article and the original paper.